# asyncValidate nested field onBlur

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux-form

I would like to asyncValidate onBlur nested field, but nothing happens. If I pass just a string everything works fine. What am I doing wrong and how to fix my code:

```
<Field
    name="array[0].code" // works fine and data saves in the right field
    type="text"
    component={renderField}
/>

const formRedux = reduxForm({
    form: 'form',
    destroyOnUnmount: false,
    forceUnregisterOnUnmount: true,
    validate,
    asyncValidate,
    asyncBlurFields: ['array[0].code'], //doesn't work out
})(formRedux);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to write it without index:

```
asyncBlurFields: ['array[].code']
```